# Gradle Artifactory and space in name

Tags: space, artifactory

I am having an artifact published with space in Artifactory. We have the POM published as well. Reference getting is:

`compile group: 'com.local', name: "Artifact Name", version: '1.3'`

If I get this, I got error below. If I put the `Artifact%20Name` then I got problem with 
`org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.parser.MetaDataParseException: inconsistent module metadata found. Descriptor: com.local:Artifact Name:1.3 Errors: bad module name: expected='Artifact%20Name' found='Artifact Name'`

Is there a way that gradle can just replace the space with `%20` to prevent the illegal character?

---

```
... 209 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 81: http://artifactory:8081/artifactory/repos/com/local/Artifact Name/1.3/Artifact Name-
1.3.pom
        at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:859)
        at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet.<init>(HttpGet.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.externalresource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRawGet(HttpClientHelper.java:66)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.externalresource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performGet(HttpClientHelper.java:70)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.externalresource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor.getResource(HttpResourceAccessor.java:46)
```

Comment: Can't you re-publish the artifact without spaces?

Comment: Thanks, it is not an option at the moment.